# post data from form that was hidden using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form that I had hidden using jquery which on click is displayed.I want to post data using php but on clicking submit nothing happens.see code

```
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 with-click-text">
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
<table class="click-text font-light "width="450px"  >
<tr>
<td>
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label> 
 <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label> 
 <td valign="top">  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"> 
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" required> 
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
   <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30"> 
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" required></textarea> 
   <input type="submit" name="mailit" id="submit" value="Submit"> 
  </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

if(isset($_POST['mailit'])) { echo"do something";}

```
  $('.with-click-text').click(
    function(e) {
$(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
            $(this).find('.click-text')
                .show()
                .css('opacity', 0)
                .delay(200)
                .animate(
                    {
                        paddingTop: '25px',
                        opacity: 1
                    },
                    'fast',
                    'linear'
                );

    $("#submit").on("click",function(e){
    $(this).submit();

            });
            });
```

Comment: You haven't added a value to the `action` property on the `form` element. This needs to the URL of the page that processes the form.

Comment: BY "nothing happens" you mean that page reload but does not show message "do something", or it not submit at all?

Comment: The location of the form end tag `</form>` is wrong.

Comment: by nothing happens I mean it does not post @MarkS  isnt leaving it blank the same as <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>@user3554382

Comment: @user3554382 if the form is submitting to the same page, then a blank value for the action attribute is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no element with id `submit`. Update your function;

```
....
$("input[type='submit']").on("click",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).submit();

});
```

You can see demo here: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/K4GrY/1)**

Comment: Well what sense does it make to prevent default and then submit? Not to mention that his form should submit even without js as it is normal form. True that his js was wrong, but it should have nothing to do with form submitting

Comment: I assumed that user will do something before submit. I put an alert there. That is why it is overridden

Comment: Thanks people @HüseyinBABAL you are a genius!It worked for me using your code.Thanks

Comment: Actually sorry problem still there.It doesn't echo back any response only the alert window pops up?Am totally confused as to where the issue is now @HüseyinBABAL

Comment: Are you posting form to same page?

Comment: yes I am.But I also tested with other page but it doesnt seem to post.Also used  
if (!empty($_POST)){
echo "hot damn";} to check for any post but nothing!!!

Comment: Could you please put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of php page and try again

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no error error reporting is on for php on wampserver as well.@Pete I think you myt have an idea where should i place it.Named the form id="contactform" then added this to the jquery script$ ("form #contactform").submit();

Comment: I said that because in order to see error, you need to open error reporting